# Samsung Galaxy Tab 7A stuck in reboot

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, tablet

My Samsung Galaxy Tab 7A is stuck in reboot mode and the hard reset won't work; it doesn't reboot to the boot menu and the power button and the volume down buttons turn it off, but it just cycles back on. And as soon as I use my password to get in, it says the tablet is starting and then freezes and then reboots.